# How to describe correctly GPIO in dts-file to power it off in the "Suspend-to-RAM" mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio, device-tree

I have GPIO-expnader tca6424 on my board. Pin 17 supplies another chips. I need to power off this chips in the "suspend-to-RAM" mode.  I described it in dts file:

```
hu_u1740: tca6424_hu_u1740@22 {
    compatible = "ti,tca6424";
    reg = <0x22>;
    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
    
    regulator@17 {
        regulator-min-microvolt = <33000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-name = "pw_bt";
        enable-active-high;
        regulator-state-mem {
                regulator-off-in-suspend;
        };
    };
};
```

I tried pin 17 as regulator but it doesn't work. If is there  ready way or i should write own driver?

Comment: Fixed voltage shared regulator is the correct approach. How do you know that the drivers of those chips a) implementing PM callbacks, b) support the regulator?

Comment: Ah and on top of that regulator uses a provider-consumer pattern, in one place you have to describe **provider**, and in other(s) **consumer(s)**.